# How do I import 101 CSV files at once into my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, file-upload, psql

I have psql set up on my MacOS terminal. It's hooked up to my PostgreSQL db running through Amazon RDS.

I have 100 CSV files (with names 1,2,3,4 up to 100). I want to bulk import them. I see there are some scripts (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168861/import-100-csv-files-into-postgresql/169089#169089), but I don't know how to run a script.

I tried copying and pasting this script -

```
for x in $(ls <folder_name>*.csv); 
do psql -c "copy table_name from '$x' csv" also; done
```

And I received these errors -

```
db=> for x in $(ls <folder_name>*.csv); 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for"
LINE 1: for x in $(ls <folder_name>...
        ^
db=> do psql -c "copy <table_name> from '$x' csv" also; done
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: do psql -c "copy <table_name> from '$x' csv" also;
```

Can you help me a) figure out the right script to bulk import these files and b) figure out how to execute the script?

Note - all the files are going to the same table, which already exists.

Comment: This's a shell script not a plpgsql script. Did you try running from shell?

Comment: I'm running it from the terminal window. My impression is that the terminal window is shell. Is that accurate?

Comment: I've since figured it out that shell is the terminal window before I access psql.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT,description TEXT);
```

And the following files

## file1.csv

```
id,description 
1,foo
```

## file2.csv

```
id,description
2,bar
```

Execute the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/user/files/"

for f in $path*.csv;do

    cat $f | psql testdb -c "COPY yourtable FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"

done
```

And there you have your data:

```
$ psql testdb -c "SELECT * FROM t"
 id | description 
----+-------------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: I gave that a try in the blank terminal window (afaik 'shell') and received this error - psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: It seems you're not able to connect to the server via `psql`. Are database and `psql` in the same machine?

Comment: Just to make it clear: you have to save this code into a text file and execute it in the terminal e.g. using `./myfile.sh`. If your file is not executable, give it the permission to be executed with `chmod +x myfile.sh`

Comment: That was an error on my part. I have since replaced "yourserver" with the psql login command to access my db. The newer version served this error - /Users/One/Documents/import_script2.txt: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/Users/One/Documents/import_script2.txt: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Is it possible you can add a sample of these CSV files in your question? Just to make sure that the problem isn't the file structure itself.

Comment: If it matters, I'm able to upload the CSVs one at a time successfully. I can't upload the CSV though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading all into same table and if the headers can be excluded, one option would be to concatenate them into a single csv.

```
bash-$ head -1 /folder_name/file1.csv > combined_file.csv

bash-$ cat folder_name/*.csv | grep -v 'headerpattern' >>combined_file.csv
```

`postgres# COPY yourtable FROM 'combined_file.csv' DELIMITER ','`

Comment: Would this approach perhaps "fail" if each csv file has its own header?